# Why Queue().get() can stop(or break) a while true loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am learning Thread and Queue, and I found that Queue().get() can stop a while loop. But I don't know why.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

def working():
    while True:
        print("loop...")
        Queue().get()         ## why here ##

for i in range(5):    
    t = Thread(target=working)
    t.start()
```

If I remove "Queue().get()", it will become a infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) tells you exactly why. `Queue.get()` blocks until an item is available unless you pass `False` as the first parameter.

Comment: If you pass `False` to `Queue.get` and the queue is empty `Queue.Empty` will be raised, so be prepared to catch the exception.